# jQuery Cycle2 Advanced Pager via API

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I've been using this jQuery Cycle2 plugin (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/api/advanced.php), and I've been trying to build a custom pager using a title from inside each slide.

The documentation for cycle 2 focuses more on data attributes in the HTML, however I need to execute the cycle2 plugin via it's javascript alternative.

I've been looking at this buildPagerLink via API but can't figure it out.

```
$('.p-slider').on('cycle-bootstrap', function(e, optionHash, API) {
    API.buildPagerLink = function(opts, slideOpts, slide) {
        //CODE TO GET H2 TITLE
    }
});
```

Basically what I want is this. Each slide has a `<h2>` element. I want the text inside that to be the link text for the pager. Sounds simple, but I can't figure it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Dave

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug with the cycle-bootstrap and therefor in order to use this with the buildPagerLink you need to bind it to the document.  The following will pull the h2 text and build the pager with it:

```
$(document).on('cycle-bootstrap', function( e, opts, API ) {
    API.buildPagerLink = function(opts, slideOpts, slide) {
       var pagerLink;
    var pagers = opts.API.getComponent( 'pager' );
    pagers.each(function() {
        var pager = $(this);

            var markup = $('<span></span>').text($('h2', slide).text());
            pagerLink = $( markup ).appendTo( pager );
        pagerLink.on( opts.pagerEvent, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            opts.API.page( pager, e.currentTarget);
        });
    });
    }
});

$('.slideshow').cycle();
```

Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/FetC8/1/

Issue as reference:  https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/157

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I do actually require an API method of fixing this problem due to the CMS I'm working with.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What I provided matches your question of providing a "javascript alternative".